# Find the radius of convergence for $\sum^{\infty}_0 n^nz^{n^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Find the radius of convergence for $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} n^nz^{n^n}$

This is not a power series, but if I define $a_k=k$ if $k=n^n$ and $a_k=0$ otherwise, I would have a power series such that  $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} n^nz^{n^n} = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} a_kz^{k} $. then we have $$\frac{1}{R}= \limsup_{k \to \infty} |a_k|^{1/k}$$**Is the following reasoning correct ?**
We are looking for $\limsup$ , and $|a_k|^{1/k} \geq 0$, therefore we can ignore the subsequence on which $|a_k|^{1/k}=0$, and only care about the subsequence for which $k=n^n$, on that subsequence we have $a_k=k$ Hence $$\frac{1}{R}= \limsup_{k \to \infty} |k|^{1/k}=1 \Rightarrow R=1 \ \  $$

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Your reasoning looks correct to me; the radius of convergence indeed is $1$.

Comment: Another question : Each term in  $f(z)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} n^nz^{n^n}$ is a term in $g(z)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} nz^{n}$ and we know that the radius of convergence of $g(z)$ is 1, so we conclude that radius of convergence of $f(z)$ is also 1. Is this an acceptable reasoning ?

Comment: Yes, that should work too

Comment: It'd work in this case too, but one should be careful with this alternate approach -- strictly speaking, it shows that radius of convergence of $f(z)$ is *at least* as big as the radius of convergence of $g(z)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasonning is correct.

We can also use a direct method. If $|z|\lt 1$, the series $\sum_k k|z|^k$ is convergent, hence so is the series with the same general term but with the sum over integers of the form $n^n$. It's clear that the radius of convergence cannot be more than $1$ since the general term is $n^n$.